# How do I go about filtering my data by the upper 50th percentile for a separate dependent variable?

Tags: r

I need to split my data so that when I use the facet_wrap I have the top 50 percentile for each year.
Here is a sample of my data:

```
# A tibble: 10,519 x 3
   Species                 Abundance Year 
   <chr>                       <dbl> <chr>
 1 Astropecten irregularis         2 2009 
 2 Asterias rubens                14 2009 
 3 Echinus esculentus              1 2009 
 4 Pagurus prideaux                1 2009 
 5 Raja clavata                    1 2009 
 6 Astropecten irregularis         4 2009 
 7 Asterias rubens                47 2009 
 8 Henricia sp.                    2 2009 
 9 Ophiura ophiura                 8 2009 
10 Solaster endeca                 1 2009 
# ... with 10,509 more rows
```

My current strategy is this:

```
Data <- All_years %>%
  group_by(Species, Year) %>%
  summarise(Abundance = sum(Abundance, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(quantile(Abundance, 0.50)<Abundance) %>%
  filter(Abundance > 50)
```

The issue is that this gives me the top 50 percentile for the whole set while I would like it to give me the top 50 for each year so I can then display it with a facet_wrap in ggplot.

Comment: I think you can just replace `summarise` with `mutate` here (and then `ungroup()` so the filters are applied across groups) to keep all the observations.

Comment: That certainly has given more spread out results, thank you.